# Azure ARM template with PowerShell deployment fails on the NIC with an InvalidResourceReference error

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-rm-template

I have an Azure generated template and parameters file for creating a simple VM. It works fine with the supplied deploy.ps1. I've updated the parameters file to create another VM in a new resource group, but it now fails with an "Invalid resource reference" error.

I've reviewed the template, but not changed it. I can see there's nothing hard-coded. The deployment creates the Network Security Group and the public IP address but then fails on the NIC. I've checked for region issues, but can't see any.

The NIC part of the template looks like this:

```
"variables": {
        "nsgId": "[resourceId(resourceGroup().name, 'Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', parameters('networkSecurityGroupName'))]",
        "vnetId": "[parameters('virtualNetworkId')]",
        "subnetRef": "[concat(variables('vnetId'), '/subnets/', parameters('subnetName'))]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
            "apiVersion": "2018-10-01",
            "name": "[parameters('networkInterfaceName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/', parameters('networkSecurityGroupName'))]",
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/publicIpAddresses/', parameters('publicIpAddressName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "ipConfigurations": [
                    {
                        "name": "ipconfig1",
                        "properties": {
                            "subnet": {
                                "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
                            },
                            "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
                            "publicIpAddress": {
                                "id": "[resourceId(resourceGroup().name, 'Microsoft.Network/publicIpAddresses', parameters('publicIpAddressName'))]"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "networkSecurityGroup": {
                    "id": "[variables('nsgId')]"
                }
            }
        },
```

The error message is:

> New-AzResourceGroupDeployment : 17:11:30 - Resource
>   Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces 'newRHserverNIC' failed with
>   message '{   "error": {
>       "code": "InvalidResourceReference",
>       "message": "Resource /subscriptions//resourceGroups/Scripttest2/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/NewvirtNet/subnets/default
>   referenced by resource /subscriptions//resourceGroups/Scripttest2/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/newRHserverNIC
>   was not found. Please make sure that the referenced resource exists,
>   and that both resources are in the same region.",
>       "details": []   } }'

Comment: Thanks for correcting my spelling. We often don't use commas before conjunctions in the UK as the conjunction is deemed sufficient to indicate that a pause may be appropriate but each to their own. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, its either of two, subnet is in a different region\different resource group\different subscription or called differently.

Comment: In the parameters file the subnet is defined as:

Comment: doesnt really matter how its defined (you omitted that), what matters is that you id doesnt match the actual resource

Comment: In the parameters file the subnet is defined as: "subnetName": { "value": "default" }. All reference to location are UKSouth. Similarly all the subscription references appear to match. Not sure what else to check.

Comment: I've told you what to check :) location should be the same. vnet name and subnet name should match. vnet has to be in the same resource group. how are you generating vnetid? in parameters

Comment: Ok, I understand what's happening now I think. The template came from a deployment of a VM in a resource group where the vNet had been created manually. Consequently the template that was derived from the VM deployment did not even contain a vNet. For my test if I created the vNet first the deployment works.

Answer (score 0):

Don't ignore `<azuredeploy.parameters.json>` file.
In my case, this file was faulty. It had a different Location than the current Resource Group, because I extracted it from a previous execution.